# Distributed Lock in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, redis, locking, jedis, redisson

I have a Spring Boot service with multiple instances. I have some job running named A. If another request comes to run the job A, while it's still running I don't want it to trigger another invocation. I need distributed lock for this. Now my service was already connecting to Redis using jedis, but jedis doesn't have any locking primitives supported by default. I tried to use Spring Integration Redis' RedisLockRegistry but it doesn't support custom TTL at lock level(https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3444). Redis official docs mention Redisson as the only java client available under Distributed Locks section(https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/distributed-locks/).
While trying to connect to a remote redis cluster I'm facing following error:

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 12.23.23.23 found
```

I added certificate to local keychain but still getting same error.

I tried creating local redis cluster, and was able to verify it standalone. But when I use local cluster to connect via Redisson I'm getting:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.ClusterStateFailureException: Could not retrieve cluster information. CLUSTER NODES returned with error.
```

Feeling out of options atm, Need help to get this redisson client running on local.